# How do I hook an Ajax request into a PHP callback?

Tags: ajax, callbacks

Following the directions here http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Administration_Side

I wrote this code:

EDITED TO INCLUDE DIE(), STILL NOT WORKING

```
function my_button() {
echo
"<script type = 'text/javascript'>
function ajaxRequest(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
        var sendData = {};
        sendData['action'] = 'my_action';
        sendData['external_id'] = '$postID';
        sendData['title'] = '$post_title';
        sendData['content'] = '$post_content';
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://lvh.me:3000/s/wp',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
            data: sendData,
            error: function(jqXHR){
                console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
            },
            success: function(data){
                window.open(data['link']);
            }
        });
    })
};
</script>
<input type='button' onclick='ajaxRequest()' value='Send' />";
}

add_action( 'dbx_post_sidebar', my_button);

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', my_action_callback);

function my_action_callback() {
  global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database
  $api_key = $_POST['api_key'];
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  $user_id = $user->ID;
  add_user_meta($user_id, 'my_api_key', $api_key);
  die();
}
```

I know that's a ton of code, but I just can't figure out where the error is.

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4):

Your url should be pointing to admin-ajax.php

```
echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
```

Comment: sorry, which url?

Comment: @KateRay `url: 'http://lvh.me:3000/s/wp'`

Answer (score 1):

> **EDIT**: I found several problems with your method.

This is how it should be done for your case, I went ahead and rewrote some things.

```
function my_button() {
echo
"<script type = 'text/javascript'>
    jQuery( document ).ready( function() {

        jQuery('input.sendajax').click( function() {

            var sendData = {
                action: 'my_action',
                external_id = $postID,
                title: '$post_title',
                content: '$post_content'
            };

            jQuery.post( ajaxurl, sendData, function( response ) {

                // You need to send some type of validation back
                // Like a 'success' variable either true or false
                // Stuff sent back is accessed through the 'response' variable, so to get the item sent back called 'success', you would use 'response.success'

                if( response.success == true ) {
                    window.open(response.link);
                } else {
                    console.log(response);
                }

            });

        });

    })
</script>
<input class='sendajax' type='button' onclick='ajaxRequest()' value='Send' />";
}

add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_button');

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

function my_action_callback() {
  global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database
  $api_key = $_POST['api_key'];
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  $user_id = $user->ID;
  add_user_meta($user_id, 'my_api_key', $api_key);

  $response = array( 'success' => true, 'link' => 'this is a response var' ); // Stuff to send back to AJAX
  echo json_encode( $response );

  die(); // Needs this
}
```

If you read the Codex carefully, and compare your code to the [code here](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Administration_Side), they are very different. You were trying to use a method most would deem appropriate but WP already can do these things for you (which I didn't even realize until a couple days ago, so don't feel bad!)

What I did is use WP's native `ajaxurl` and `jQuery.post` method to call `admin-ajax.php` and send the `sendData` info to a function that will do some stuff with those variables, and then echo back a `response` so you can do something with that as well.

Comment: yeah, actually I tried that as well. No luck.

Comment: @KateRay I updated my answer.

Comment: Hm, that code throws a 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' for this line: external_id = <?php $postID; ?>

Comment: @KateRay I updated my answer yet again with some other missed issues, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Hmmm, but then where do I specify the external API's url? It's lvh.me for now, but obviously will be pointing to a real url soon.

Comment: Well with this method you are trying to call this from the administrative side, I don't think this method is the one you are looking for. Alternatively, you can try and change `ajaxurl` to the URL to the API (don't forget to put 'single quotes' around it), but I _doubt_ and _don't know_ if that will work. Also, it really depends on what you are trying to do and what API you are trying to implement.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is send some Wordpress data to my own website (the external API endpoint is my own), process it, and return an API key that I then store as metadata with the Wordpress user, so that I can authorize subsequent requests to my API. Maybe I'm headed in the wrong direction with this code though...

Comment: @KateRay Is there any way you can do something like `file_get_contents( url.to/api.php?var=somequery&var2=another )` or another method in the callback and then parse the response from that, then send it back to the AJAX response with the method I showed you above?

Comment: To be honest, I don't quite understand what you mean. The order of things needs to be 1) Send data to my API. 2) Get response from my API. 3) Use some of that response data to update the WordPress user.

Comment: @Kate Ray - WordPress ajax is for making ajax requests to your WP install, making external API requests doesn't involve WordPress. The order of execution would be to make your external API call, then within the response javascript function make a call to WordPress via ajax to do whatever updating you want to do with WordPress. so basically, Jared's ajax code here would go within your ajax API call's response function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to break down what you are doing into two parts.

1 /  Query your external api, and then return your API key

2 / Associate the API key with a user.

So, I would first query your API via a standard ajax call, and then in the success handler of that first ajax call, run your internal wp admin-ajax call to associate the user with the API key.